# Substituting values in 3j symbols

Tags: bugs, replacement, special-functions, physics

**Bug introduced in 8.0 or earlier and fixed in 10.2.0**

---

I believe these three expressions should give the same answer of `-1/Sqrt[3]`, but the first gives `+1/Sqrt[3]` whereas the second and third give the correct value, using *Mathematica 8*. What am I doing wrong?

```
ThreeJSymbol[{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, c -> 0}   
ThreeJSymbol[{a, 0} /. a -> 1, {b, 0} /. b -> 1, {c, 0} /. c -> 0]  
ThreeJSymbol[{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}]
```

Comment: The same incorrect result also happens when I replace `ThreeJSymbol` with `ClebschGordan` in the first line.

Comment: Same problem in Mathematica 10

Comment: This bug was reported to and acknowledged by Wolfram Technical Support (CASE:1381596). I suggest editing the question to add the tags: "bugs" and "physics" for future reference. Probably  the answer by @Jens should be accepted.

Comment: The problem is still present in Mathematica 10.1.0

Comment: The problem seems to be fixed in version 10.2 Windows 7 64, anybody can confirm in other platforms?

Answer (score 4):

Just to expand on what @eldo has written.

I found that this odd behavior happens for all odd $n$ values where $n$ is the argument of this function:-

```
f[n_] := Module[{r1, r2, r3},
r1 = ThreeJSymbol[{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}] /. {a -> n, b -> n, 
 c -> 0};
r2 = ThreeJSymbol[{a, 0} /. a -> n, {b, 0} /. b -> n, {c, 0} /. 
 c -> 0];
r3 = ThreeJSymbol[{n, 0}, {n, 0}, {0, 0}];
{r1, r2, r3}]

f[3]
(*{1/Sqrt[7], -(1/Sqrt[7]), -(1/Sqrt[7])}*)
```

But when $n$ is even all the answers agree.

```
f[2]
(*{1/Sqrt[5], 1/Sqrt[5], 1/Sqrt[5]}*)
```

So there seems to be an extra minus sign coming from the $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ part before evaluating these three at (0,0,0).

We can see that here in $f_1(a)$ where we keep $(m_1,m_2,m_3)$ as it is and check for different $a$ values

```
f1[a_] := ThreeJSymbol[{a, m1}, {a, m2}, {0, m3}]
```

If you run this you will see that for all odd values of $a$ there is an overall minus sign which then creeps into the final answer because of the reason @eldo mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

The same problem also appears in the related function [`ClebschGordan`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ClebschGordan.html).
This is indeed a bug which appears when *Mathematica* is given symbolic parameters instead of specific integers or half-integers. We can check that the first result in the question is incorrect by using the explicit sum definition of `ThreeJSymbol` given in the [documentation under Properties](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ThreeJSymbol.html):

```
Clear[threeJSymbol];
threeJSymbol[{j1_, m1_}, {j2_, m2_}, {j3_, 
   m3_}] := (1/Sqrt[(1 + j1 + j2 + j3)!])*(-1)^(-j1 + j2 + m3)*
  Sqrt[(j1 + j2 - j3)!]*Sqrt[(j1 - j2 + j3)!]*Sqrt[(-j1 + j2 + j3)!]*
  Sqrt[(j1 - m1)!]*Sqrt[(j1 + m1)!]*Sqrt[(j2 - m2)!]*Sqrt[(j2 + m2)!]*
  Sqrt[(j3 - m3)!]*Sqrt[(j3 + m3)!]*KroneckerDelta[m1 + m2, -m3]*
  Sum[(-1)^k/((j1 + j2 - j3 - k)!*
      k!*(j1 - k - m1)!*(-j2 + j3 + k + m1)!*(-j1 + j3 + k - 
         m2)!*(j2 - k + m2)!), {k, Max[0, j2 - j3 - m1, j1 - j3 + m2],
     Min[j1 - m1, j2 + m2]}]
```

With this, all three results agree:

```
threeJSymbol[{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}] /. {a -> 1, b -> 1, 
  c -> 0}
threeJSymbol[{a, 0} /. a -> 1, {b, 0} /. b -> 1, {c, 0} /. c -> 0]
threeJSymbol[{1, 0}, {1, 0}, {0, 0}]

(* ==> -(1/Sqrt[3]) *)

(* ==> -(1/Sqrt[3]) *)

(* ==> -(1/Sqrt[3]) *)
```

Instead of using this slower definition, we can still make replacements in `ThreeJSymbol` by wrapping it in [`Unevaluated`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Unevaluated.html):

```
Unevaluated[ThreeJSymbol[{a, 0}, {b, 0}, {c, 0}]] /. {a -> 1,
   b -> 1, c -> 0}

(* ==> -(1/Sqrt[3]) *)
```

Answer (score 2):

Line1: `ThreeJSymbol` is evaluated before replacement. Line2: `ThreeJSymbol` is evaluated after replacement. To give another example:

```
D[x^2, x] /. x -> 2
```

> 4

```
D[x^2 /. x -> 2, x]
```

> 0

Comment: Although this is true, I don't think that it explains the incorrect behavior.